# Python variables in Spark dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, variables, pyspark

Being a bit new to Pyspark I've hit an issue where passing Python variables into Spark commands is concerned. I need to vary the year in a spark condition so I have a variable `CurrentYear = '2022'`.
In spark I want to compare a column with that value, so something like

```
.withColumn('IsCurrentYear',when(col('ColumnName') == CurrentYear, lit('Y')) .otherwise(Lit('n')))
```

I've tried every construct I can think of (asterisks, curly brackets etc.) except obviously the right one.

Is there a simple way of doing this?

Thanks

```
lit('{CurrentYear}')
{CurrentYear}
*CurrentYear
```

No success with any of these

Answer (score 0):

Just `lit(CurrentYear)` will work, which would be equivalent to `lit('2022')`

```
CurrentYear = '2022'
.withColumn('IsCurrentYear',when(col('ColumnName') == lit(CurrentYear), lit('Y')).otherwise(lit('n')))
```